# How to Extract QR tag on android from an image containing lots of other data?

Tags: android, qr-code, object-detection

I want to extract QR tag from an image containing lot of data. Something like object detection of OpenCV. After detecting that the image contains a QR tag, it should be extracted, magnified and saved. for the decoder to decode it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are looking for this [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) .

Please refer to some of the test cases [images](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/test/data/benchmark/) and [source code](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/test/src/com/google/zxing/common/)

[image: Some of test case image used to decode qr code]

Comment: I meant if the image is of resolution  say, 3128 x 2488 containing a QR tag of about 64x64 or a bit larger and rest other features. Will [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) or [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) be able to detect that? 

Thanks!